# How to find the biggest random number in specified value in C?

Tags: c, visual-studio, random

How can I save and print the biggest random number here?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>   
void main()
{
  int  i,max=0;

srand(time(NULL));

printf("rand gives value between 1-1000\n");
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    printf("%d ", rand() % 1000 + 1);
}
printf("\nMax is %d", max);
getch();
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly printing the value, you can save it in a temporary and compare it with `max`:

```
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    int r = rand() %1000 + 1;
    printf("%d ", r);
    if(r>max) max = r;
}
```